# Encryption based on boolean satisfiability?

Tags: computer-science, cryptography

We got sketch of algorithm for public key encryption based on satisfiability
of hidden boolean formula. It is easy to break
in its current form, but we are interested if it can be improved.

Alice chooses boolean formula $\phi$ on variables $x_1...x_n$
with a known satisfying assignment $S$ and another boolean for
formula $\psi$ on variables $x_1...x_k,y_1..y_m$.

Let $\Phi=(\psi \land \lnot \phi) \oplus y_1$.

Observe that $\Phi(S)=y_1$.

Alices' public key is $\Phi$ and her private key is $S$.

To encode one bit of message $m$ set $Y_1=m$ and the rest of $y_i$
random bits.

The encryption is $\Phi'=\Phi(Y_i)$, boolean formula *only* on variables $x_i$.

The decryption is $\Phi'(S)=m=Y_1$.

So far we have not defined in what form $F$ the boolean formulas
are given, which is critical.

1. $F$ must hide the location of $Y_1$ in the cypher text.
2. $F$ must not allow easily find solution of $\phi$, which
   appears in the public key. (It might be even hard to recognize
   $\phi$ from the public key).

Candidates for $F$ are read several times binary decision diagrams
BDD, branching program.

Question:

> Is it known that this won't work?

> Is the form $F$ BDD known to fail?